# How to Set Textfield in flutter to accept only certain values specified from a list or variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am working on a web app where users can post stuffs and make them more accessible by associating the posts with tags. so my idea is similar to stackoverflow's way of giving tags to posts, I am creating a Textfield with which will accept only few tags(string values) which I will create from a list and users can put them in their post. But I aint getting how to implement this as textfield has only few keyboardtypes... and I what I want to achieve is if I entered a value from a that list then it should act like a chip text(tag).
or Is there any other way to do this,

your help is appreciated,
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. you can use the [flutter_tagging](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tagging) package on the PUB

It has supports for `Web`

The gif below explains what you want to achieve

[image]

Comment: thanks for your contribution but I only want to use textfield no plugin as my app is already full of plugins right now and I am now avoiding them for my app size and performance

Answer (score 1):

You can find an implementation of a Chip Input Field type widget here:

Latest: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/c6c0f1f1baca326a389a9aec47886ad6

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// See: https://twitter.com/shakil807/status/1042127387515858949
// https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/pchmn/materialchips
// https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager

void main() => runApp(ChipsDemoApp());

class ChipsDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
        accentColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: DemoScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoScreenState createState() => _DemoScreenState();
}

class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Material Chips Input'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'normal'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ChipsInput<AppProfile>(
                decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search), hintText: 'Profile search'),
                findSuggestions: _findSuggestions,
                onChanged: _onChanged,
                chipBuilder: (BuildContext context, ChipsInputState<AppProfile> state, AppProfile profile) {
                  return InputChip(
                    key: ObjectKey(profile),
                    label: Text(profile.name),
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imageUrl),
                    ),
                    onDeleted: () => state.deleteChip(profile),
                    onSelected: (_) => _onChipTapped(profile),
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  );
                },
                suggestionBuilder: (BuildContext context, ChipsInputState<AppProfile> state, AppProfile profile) {
                  return ListTile(
                    key: ObjectKey(profile),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imageUrl),
                    ),
                    title: Text(profile.name),
                    subtitle: Text(profile.email),
                    onTap: () => state.selectSuggestion(profile),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onChipTapped(AppProfile profile) {
    print('$profile');
  }

  void _onChanged(List<AppProfile> data) {
    print('onChanged $data');
  }

  Future<List<AppProfile>> _findSuggestions(String query) async {
    if (query.length != 0) {
      return mockResults.where((profile) {
        return profile.name.contains(query) || profile.email.contains(query);
      }).toList(growable: false);
    } else {
      return const <AppProfile>[];
    }
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------

const mockResults = <AppProfile>[
  AppProfile('Stock Man', 'stock@man.com', 'https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4057996.jpg'),
  AppProfile('Paul', 'paul@google.com', 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/person-stock-image-png.png'),
  AppProfile('Fred', 'fred@google.com',
      'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/feeling-great-about-my-corporate-choices-picture-id507296326'),
  AppProfile('Bera', 'bera@flutter.io',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png'),
  AppProfile('John', 'john@flutter.io',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png'),
  AppProfile('Thomas', 'thomas@flutter.io',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png'),
  AppProfile('Norbert', 'norbert@flutter.io',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png'),
  AppProfile('Marina', 'marina@flutter.io',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png'),
];

class AppProfile {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String imageUrl;

  const AppProfile(this.name, this.email, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) || other is AppProfile && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Profile{$name}';
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------

typedef ChipsInputSuggestions<T> = Future<List<T>> Function(String query);
typedef ChipSelected<T> = void Function(T data, bool selected);
typedef ChipsBuilder<T> = Widget Function(BuildContext context, ChipsInputState<T> state, T data);

class ChipsInput<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChipsInput({
    Key key,
    this.decoration = const InputDecoration(),
    @required this.chipBuilder,
    @required this.suggestionBuilder,
    @required this.findSuggestions,
    @required this.onChanged,
    this.onChipTapped,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final InputDecoration decoration;
  final ChipsInputSuggestions findSuggestions;
  final ValueChanged<List<T>> onChanged;
  final ValueChanged<T> onChipTapped;
  final ChipsBuilder<T> chipBuilder;
  final ChipsBuilder<T> suggestionBuilder;

  @override
  ChipsInputState<T> createState() => ChipsInputState<T>();
}

class ChipsInputState<T> extends State<ChipsInput<T>> implements TextInputClient {
  static const kObjectReplacementChar = 0xFFFC;

  Set<T> _chips = Set<T>();
  List<T> _suggestions;
  int _searchId = 0;

  FocusNode _focusNode;
  TextEditingValue _value = TextEditingValue();
  TextInputConnection _connection;

  String get text => String.fromCharCodes(
        _value.text.codeUnits.where((ch) => ch != kObjectReplacementChar),
      );

  bool get _hasInputConnection => _connection != null && _connection.attached;

  void requestKeyboard() {
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      _openInputConnection();
    } else {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
    }
  }

  void selectSuggestion(T data) {
    setState(() {
      _chips.add(data);
      _updateTextInputState();
      _suggestions = null;
    });
    widget.onChanged(_chips.toList(growable: false));
  }

  void deleteChip(T data) {
    setState(() {
      _chips.remove(data);
      _updateTextInputState();
    });
    widget.onChanged(_chips.toList(growable: false));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _focusNode.addListener(_onFocusChanged);
  }

  void _onFocusChanged() {
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      _openInputConnection();
    } else {
      _closeInputConnectionIfNeeded();
    }
    setState(() {
      // rebuild so that _TextCursor is hidden.
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode?.dispose();
    _closeInputConnectionIfNeeded();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _openInputConnection() {
    if (!_hasInputConnection) {
      _connection = TextInput.attach(this, TextInputConfiguration());
      _connection.setEditingState(_value);
    }
    _connection.show();
  }

  void _closeInputConnectionIfNeeded() {
    if (_hasInputConnection) {
      _connection.close();
      _connection = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var chipsChildren = _chips
        .map<Widget>(
          (data) => widget.chipBuilder(context, this, data),
        )
        .toList();

    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    chipsChildren.add(
      Container(
        height: 32.0,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              text,
              style: theme.textTheme.subhead.copyWith(
                height: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
            _TextCaret(
              resumed: _focusNode.hasFocus,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: requestKeyboard,
          child: InputDecorator(
            decoration: widget.decoration,
            isFocused: _focusNode.hasFocus,
            isEmpty: _value.text.length == 0,
            child: Wrap(
              children: chipsChildren,
              spacing: 4.0,
              runSpacing: 4.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _suggestions?.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return widget.suggestionBuilder(context, this, _suggestions[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateEditingValue(TextEditingValue value) {
    final oldCount = _countReplacements(_value);
    final newCount = _countReplacements(value);
    setState(() {
      if (newCount < oldCount) {
        _chips = Set.from(_chips.take(newCount));
      }
      _value = value;
    });
    _onSearchChanged(text);
  }

  int _countReplacements(TextEditingValue value) {
    return value.text.codeUnits.where((ch) => ch == kObjectReplacementChar).length;
  }

  @override
  void performAction(TextInputAction action) {
    _focusNode.unfocus();
  }

  void _updateTextInputState() {
    final text = String.fromCharCodes(_chips.map((_) => kObjectReplacementChar));
    _value = TextEditingValue(
      text: text,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: text.length),
      composing: TextRange(start: 0, end: text.length),
    );
    _connection.setEditingState(_value);
  }

  void _onSearchChanged(String value) async {
    final localId = ++_searchId;
    final results = await widget.findSuggestions(value);
    if (_searchId == localId && mounted) {
      setState(() => _suggestions = results.where((profile) => !_chips.contains(profile)).toList(growable: false));
    }
  }
}

class _TextCaret extends StatefulWidget {
  const _TextCaret({
    Key key,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    this.resumed = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Duration duration;
  final bool resumed;

  @override
  _TextCursorState createState() => _TextCursorState();
}

class _TextCursorState extends State<_TextCaret> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _displayed = false;
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(widget.duration, _onTimer);
  }

  void _onTimer(Timer timer) {
    setState(() => _displayed = !_displayed);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: 0.7,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: _displayed && widget.resumed ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        child: Container(
          width: 2.0,
          color: theme.primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```